# Using curly braces in JavaScript in Play Framework template

Tags: templates, scala, playframework-2.0

I have passed a list of titles that I have passed through from my controller:

```
@titles:List[String]
```

I want to cycle through generating some html headings with {mmm} appearing after:

```
@titles.map { title =>
  <h1>{title} {mmm}</h1>
}
```

Clearly there is a problem as it will try and find a variable called mmm. How do I escape the brackets?

Or is there a more idiomatic way to generate the HTML that doesn't involve mapping the list? Very new to this!

Comment: Interestingly enough, even if they aren't being executed as scala, the twirl compiler will fail if you have unmatched curly braces inside the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to escape curly brackets in Play—unlike in Scala's XML literals, they don't have any special meaning in Play templates except after an `@`.

You should be able to write the following:

```
@titles.map { title =>
  <h1>@{title} {mmm}</h1>
}
```

And get `<h1>Whatever Title {mmm}</hq>`, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Incidentally in the work I was doing the problem seems to have been caused by using round brackets for the map.

Answer (score 3):

Travis' answer demonstrates one possibility (for that you asked for) and it's correct. On the other hand you can also meet other cases and you need to keep in mind  other tricks:

for an example this **will fail**:

```
@for(title <- titles){
    Title: @title {mmm} <br/>
}
```

But this **will work** (thanks Travis)

```
@for(title <- titles) { 
    Title: @{title} {mmm} <br/> 
}
```

And this **will work** as well

```
@for(title <- titles){
    Title: @title - <b>something else without bracets</b> <br/>
}
```

#### Alternative

Alternatively you can create for an example `toBrackets()` method in your model and call it in your template (Java sample)

```
public String toBrackets(String string) {
    return "{" + string + "}";
}
```

in template:

```
@for(title <- titles){
    Title: @title @title.toBrackets("mmm") <br/>
}
```

Comment: I don't get it—I'm 99% certain `Title: @{title} {mmm} <br/>` will work as desired. Why would you need `toBrackets`?

Comment: @TravisBrown : it will work of course as you showed in 'your' case, but not in `@for(...){...}` loop, I checked it of course before writing the answer and therefore wrote additional one

Comment: Are you sure? `@for(title <- titles) { Title: @{title} {mmm}<br/> }` works for me.

Comment: @TravisBrown Hmmm we are right... both... :) see my edited answer, thanks for help with resolving this 'puzzle'

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer so thoroughly, I'll go through your examples.

Comment: How about add only one curly brace? I get `Unmatched bracket` error. Yes, i can create method in model. But is there another way?

Answer (score 3):

If it is not part of JS or other code, and used just to present in the view, then we can use HTML entitles

```
&#123; for left curly brace
&#125; for right curly brace
```

The result:

```
{ for left curly brace
} for right curly brace
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create variables `@LeftBracket` = `{` and `@RightBracket` = `}`, and then this should work:

```
@titles.map { title =>
  <h1>{title} @{LeftBracket}mmm@RightBracket</h1>
}
```

A side note somewhat related to your question:

My impression is that unless the brackets are matched (that is, a `}` for each `{`),
template compilation fails, so perhaps `@RightBracket` is the only way to insert a single `}`?   This'd be useful in case you needed to write:

```
@titles.map { title =>
   hello :-}
}
```

:-}